# "Fragmentation" after retargeting. How to troubleshoot these?

Tags: animation, auto-rig-pro

I'm getting some tiny "fragmentations" (not sure what to call them) and a bit of stretching after retargeting. Everything else works perfectly. How do I clean these up? The source and target bones are exact copies of each other (but not the mesh). I'm using AutoRig Pro to retarget. See image.

[image]